# cmake cross-compilation with sysroot returns wrong include paths

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am having an issue when trying to cross-compile (for an arm target) and including packages through cmake.

Compilation works fine when compiled locally and also when cross-compiled without package dependencies.

My toolchain file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /path/to/sysroot/)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /path/to/sysroot/)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

And in the `CMakeFileList` I have a few `find_packages`:

```
find_package(pack1 REQUIRED)
find_package(pack2 REQUIRED)
message("--${pack1_INCLUDE_DIRS}--")
message("--${pack2_INCLUDE_DIRS}--")
include_directories(${pack1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${pack2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

When displaying the include directories variables, only the first one in the list is prefixed with the `sysroot` path. I got something like this:

```
--/path/to/sysroot/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/include/xmlrpcpp--
```

Of course the compilation failed, as some headers do not correspond to the target system.

Why is cmake not prefixing the entire list of directories (they are present in the `sysroot` folder)?

Aren't `CMAKE_SYSROOT` and `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)` sufficient to get cmake to look only in this directory or am I missing something here?

Note: there is no difference with and without the `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /path/to/sysroot/)` in the toolchain instructions.

#### Edit 1:

Explicitly setting the include paths (`${pack1_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${pack2_INCLUDE_DIRS}`) to point only to the sysroot path does solve the compilation issue but then lead to a linker error (no explicit message) which suggests that 1)the extra `/usr/include` entries are the problem and 2) the `${pack1_LIBRARIES}` variables are also incorrect.

#### Edit 2:

Following @Tsyvarev answer which explains why this cannot be directly achieved. One solution (a bit hacky) is to extract the name of the libraries to be included from the `find_package` and force cmake to look for them in the sysroot folder. The code below does work for my use case:

```
#Reset libraries towards sysroot only
foreach(lib_path ${pack1_LIBRARIES} ${pack2_LIBRARIES})
    string(REPLACE "/" ";" lib_path_list ${lib_path}) #Breakdown path in list
    list(REVERSE lib_path_list)
    list(GET lib_path_list 0 lib) #Get last element (library name)
    find_library(new_path ${lib} PATHS ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}) #Force to look for it in actual sysroot path
    list(APPEND LIBRARIES ${new_path}) #Add it to LIBRARIES list
    unset(new_path CACHE) #Clear variable to allow new search
endforeach()
```

Comment: `CMAKE_SYSROOT` (and `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`) is just a prefix for for paths, **searched** by different `find_*` commands: `find_library`, `find_path`, `find_package`(only in CONFIG mode). E.g. if you have `pack1Config.cmake` script (which is consumed by `find_package(pack1 REQUIRED)`) and this script **sets** include directories to `/usr/include`, then CMake doesn't transform this path. In other words, CMake packages you use in your project should be properly **cross-compiled** with given **sysroot**. You cannot, e.g. take the package compiled on the target machine and expect it to work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev this makes complete sense now! I believe I was too optimistic on cmake flexibility. So unless each package is cross-compiled, find_package will mess up. I imagine the solution here is thus to link directly and let the sysroot set the paths? Anyway, happy to accept this answer if you post it.

Comment: Just a note: CMake *automatically* uses `CMAKE_SYSROOT` as one of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` paths (in terms of prefixing other paths), so there is no need in adding sysroot path to the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable; setting only `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `CMAKE_SYSROOT` (and `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`) re-roots only those paths, which are **searched** by different `find_*` commands: `find_library`, `find_path`, `find_package`(only search path for package file is modified).

E.g. if `find_library` searches under `/usr/lib` by default, then with `CMAKE_SYSROOT` set it will search under `${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib` instead.

However, if one calls

```
include_directories("/usr/include")
```

then the `/usr/include` path remain unchanged even when cross-compiling.

If `find_package(pack1)` is run in `MODULE` mode and uses `Findpack1.cmake` script for locate settings of `pack1` package, then that `Findpack1.cmake` script would use `find_library` and `find_path` calls. Thus, setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT` would force this script to search libraries and headers under the sysroot and return appropriate paths.

But if `find_package(pack1)` is run in `CONFIG` mode and uses `pack1Config.cmake` script for locate settings of `pack1` package, then that `pack1Config.cmake` could use **absolute paths** of the libraries and include directories. In that case CMake does NOT transform these absolute paths, so they become wrong when cross-compiling.

Actually, CMake provides mechanisms and rules which could help in writing **relocatable** `XXXConfig.cmake` scripts. But not all config scripts follow these rules.

If a project `pack1` provides `pack1Config.cmake` script which is *non-relocatable* in terms of cross-compiling, then you need to build this project as cross-compiled with the same sysroot.

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration won't recursively append all the sub directories to your include paths.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /path/to/sysroot/)
```

In your code the `include "*.h"` should be relatively against to `/path/to/sysroot/`.

Instead of using the toolchain file, try to pass `--sysroot` from your cmake command line which should always work.

Comment: Thanks, but to what I can see the `--sysroot` option is already properly passed onto the compiler and linker commands: `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/path/to/sysroot/ ...` but indeed the build commands also haveinclude flags: `-I/usr/include` which I suspect are causing the issue. Are you suggesting something like `cmake -DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/path/to/sysroot/`? This does not appear to change anything (same compilation flags and same error).

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is a proper way for specify sysroot for the cross-compiled project.